# Circular background behind a transparent png image

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I have a div that contains a background image of size 64x64. I would like to give this div a circular shadow or radial background when the user hover's over the div with the mouse.

If I simply give the div a box shadow, the shadow is cast around in a square shape. If I make the div have a radius, then I will need to make my div bigger than 64x64 so that it doesn't crop?

Have a look at at the following example that illustrates what I am trying to describe:
http://jsfiddle.net/rNeaZ/2/

The 4th example (shown in link above) in particular doesn't suit what I am after because:

- it's size is much larger than my 64x64 image
- the image looks to have a circular border now, which is not what I want; I am after a circular shadow or background behind it

Answer (score 1):

It will probably just be easier and more effective **and** more efficient to add a nice radial shadow to an [*image sprite*](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) and change the location of the background image on hover.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to add an appropriate `background-color`, but that would only work when you need an offset of 0 0, like your example.

The more general case would be to create a pseudo-element and apply the shadow and background color to that. I can describe this in more detail if the first idea doesn't apply to your case.